# Trying to host minecraft Via Hostinger and Forge 1.12.2 won't allow the console to launch

Tags: java, server, minecraft, minecraft-forge

[Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFGxQ.png)

If any other info is needed, please don't hesitate to let me know. I genuinely don't know the issue.

Comment: Hi, don't include error log as picture, prefer copy/paste

Comment: There's a java version mismatch. What version of Java is this website using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft Forge 1.12.2 is not compatible with the most recent versions of Java. I recommend you to install Java 8 and start the server with that Java version, as most Forge mods that were released around that time targetted Java 7 or 8. If you keep having issues, try to start a clean Forge server without mods first. This way you can know whether there is a problem with your setup or with a mod that you've installed.